# Two accumulators in reduce / fold

Tags: kotlin, functional-programming

Suppose I have a data list `val data = listOf("F 1", "D 2", "U 1", "D 3", "F 10")` and I wanna perform the given logic on each element.

I have to add `var acc2 = 0` outside to do this. I wonder is there any possible to get two accumulators in fold / reduce that this method be without side effect.

```
val data = listOf("F 1", "D 2", "U 1", "D 3", "F 10")
var acc2 = 0
val result = data.fold(0, { acc, str ->
    when (str.split(" ")[0]) {
        "F" -> {
            acc + str.split(" ")[1].toInt() * acc2
        }
        "D" -> {
            acc2 += str.split(" ")[1].toInt()
            acc
        }
        "U" -> {
            acc2 -= str.split(" ")[1].toInt()
            acc
        }
        else -> {
            acc
        }
    }
})
```

Comment: Just use a pair tuple or another composite accumulator?

Comment: @Endzeit this tagging is being discussed [on Meta](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/413443/3001761).

Comment: any chance that you are doing https://adventofcode.com/2021/day/2 ? :P

Comment: You are right, I am participating "advent of code", I have solved day 2 but my solution was not clearly as I wanted ;)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use a simple object, wrapping both values.

```kotlin
data class Position(var horizontal: Int, var depth: Int)

val data = listOf("F 1", "D 2", "U 1", "D 3", "F 10")

val result = data.fold(Position(0, 0)) { position, str ->
    val (command, value) = str.split(" ")

    when (command) {
        "F" -> position.horizontal += value.toInt()
        "D" -> position.depth += value.toInt()
        "U" -> position.depth -= value.toInt()
    }

    position
}
```

If you don't want to create a new class for this, you may utilize the class `Pair<Int, Int>` from the stdlib of Kotlin.

Answer (score 1):

Thanks to above comments I have tried to use `Pair` in my solution

```
val result = data.fold(Pair(0, 0), { accs, str ->
    val (command, value) = str.split(" ")
    when (command) {
        "F" -> Pair(accs.first + value.toInt() * accs.second, accs.second)
        "D" -> Pair(accs.first, accs.second + value.toInt())
        "U" -> Pair(accs.first, accs.second - value.toInt())
        else -> accs
     }
})
```